# Generic UITableViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do I create generic TableViewController with array of items to be displayed? I've created [a sample project](https://github.com/libec/StackOverflow/tree/master/05-GenericTableViewControllers) demonstrating that the standard approach doesn't seem to work because you inherit from Objective-C class. The main point being this compiles but crashes at runtime:

```
class PickerViewController<T where T: CellDescription>: UITableViewController {
}

...

let pickerController = PickerViewController<Person>(style: .Plain)
```

Do you guys know any workaround **other** than passing closure to the `UITableViewController` descendant describing how to display model in the cell or using array of `Any` or `AnyObject`? I'd like to use the generics (not casting) because it seems like the proper way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't support generic on non-generic classes.
There is bypass of generic TableViewController: https://github.com/dimpiax/FlexibleTableViewController